# Eliminando elementos luego de usar append a través de bootbox

Tags: jquery

Estoy tratando de eliminar elementos con .remove() recientemente agregados con .append() y lo hago vía BootBox.js, pero no lo elimina, lo hace sólo luego de refrescar la página, éste es el código que utilizo:

```
window.BorraDir = function (aDir)
{
    var Msg = '<div id="spinner" style="display:none;"><img src="/Imagenes/spinner.svg" height="60px"/> Procesando...</div> ' +
        '<div id="boot_message">¿Seguro deseas eliminar éste directorio?</div>';

    var Dialog = bootbox.dialog({
        title: "Eliminar Directorio",
        message: Msg,
        buttons: [
            {
                label: "Sí",
                className: "btn btn-danger boot-yes",
                callback: function () {

                    var Fila = "";

                    if (aDir === 0 || aDir === null && aDir === undefined) {
                        bootbox.alert("No se ha determinado el directorio!");

                        return false;
                    }

                    Fila = "#dir-" + aDir;

                    var Datos = {
                        Id: aDir
                    };

                    //Mostramos el spinner y escondemos el mensaje
                    $("#spinner").show();
                    $("#boot_message").hide();

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/Directorios/BorrarDir",
                        data: Datos,
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function (data) {
                            if (data.tipo === 'error') {
                                bootbox.alert(data.message);

                                //Es un error, volvemos a mostrar el mensaje
                                //y escondemos el spinner
                                $("#spinner").hide();
                                $("#boot_message").show();

                            } else if (data.tipo === 'ok') {

                                Dialog.modal('hide');  

                                $(Fila).fadeOut().remove();                                    
                            }
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                            bootbox.alert("Error: " + xhr.responseText);

                            //Es un error, volvemos a mostrar el mensaje
                            //y escondemos el spinner
                            $("#spinner").hide();
                            $("#boot_message").show();
                        }
                    })

                    return false;
                }
            },
            {
                label: "No",
                className: "btn btn-primary",
                callback: function () {

                }
            }
        ],
        show: false,
        onEscape: function () {
            Dialog.modal("hide");
        }
    });

    Dialog.modal("show");
}
```

El ajax dentro del callback funciona correctamente pero no me elimina el elemento, leyendo por ahí se dice que se debe utilizar .delegate() ó .on(), pero tampoco logro hacerlo funcionar.

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?.

Comment: ¿Hace el fadeout correctamente? ¿Qué valor tiene fila si haces un `console.log(Fila)` justo antes del remove? ¿cambia el resultado si en lugar de hacer `var Fila = ""` pones `let Fila = ""`?

Comment: No hace el fadeOut(), el valor de FIla tanto con var y let son correctos me devuelve `#dir-1027` en ambos casos.

Answer (score 0):

He descubierto que .append() y .remove() en algunas situaciones no se llevan bien, en su lugar he utilizado .appendTo() y el .remove() funciona correctamente.

EDIT:

Así queda con appendTo:

```
$('<tr id="dir-' + data.id + '">' +
    ' <td style= "width:1%;"><span style="width: ' + Sangria + 'px; display: block;"></Span></td> ' +
    ' <td style="width:1%;"> ' +
    '   <a href="#" class="collapse-icon-dir" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-dir-' + data.id + '" data-icon="#chevron-dir-' + data.id + '"><i id="chevron-dir-' + data.id + '" class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>' +
    ' </td > ' +
    ' <td style="width:2%"> ' +
    '     <div class="dropdown"> ' +
    '        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> ' +
    '            <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i> <span class="caret"></span> ' +
    '        </button> ' +
    '        <ul class="dropdown-menu"> ' +
    '            <li><a href="#" onclick="CreaDirectorio(' + ProcesoId + ',' + data.id + ')" data-id="' + data.id + '"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i> Nuevo Directorio</a></li>' +
    '            <li><a href="/Fichas/CreaFicha?Id=' + data.id + '"><i class="fa fa-file-text"></i>Crear Ficha Técnica</a></li> ' +
    '            <li><a href="/Directorios/SubirDocumento?DirectorioId=' + data.id + '"><i class="fa fa-file"></i>Subir Documento</a></li > ' +
    '            <li><a href="#" onclick="BorraDir(' + data.id + ' )" data-id=' + data.id + '"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>Eliminar Directorio</a></li> ' +
    '        </ul> ' +
    '    </div> ' +
    ' </td> ' +
    ' <td style="width:96%">' + Datos.Nombre + '</td> ' +
    '</tr>' +
    '<tr id="collapse-dir-' + data.id + '" class="collapse"> ' +
    '    <td colspan="4"> '+
    '        <table class="table table-condensed table-hover" id="table-dirs-' + data.id + '"> ' +
    '            <tbody> ' +
    '            </tbody> ' +
    '        </table> ' +
    '    </td>' +
    '</tr>').appendTo(Fila).hide().fadeIn(1000);
```

Antes con Append:

```
$(Fila).append('<tr id="dir-' + data.id + '">' +
    ' <td style= "width:1%;"><span style="width: ' + Sangria + 'px; display: block;"></Span></td> ' +
    ' <td style="width:1%;"> ' +
    '   <a href="#" class="collapse-icon-dir" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-dir-' + data.id + '" data-icon="#chevron-dir-' + data.id + '"><i id="chevron-dir-' + data.id + '" class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>' +
    ' </td > ' +
    ' <td style="width:2%"> ' +
    '     <div class="dropdown"> ' +
    '        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> ' +
    '            <i class="fa fa-folder-open"></i> <span class="caret"></span> ' +
    '        </button> ' +
    '        <ul class="dropdown-menu"> ' +
    '            <li><a href="#" onclick="CreaDirectorio(' + ProcesoId + ',' + data.id + ')" data-id="' + data.id + '"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i> Nuevo Directorio</a></li>' +
    '            <li><a href="/Fichas/CreaFicha?Id=' + data.id + '"><i class="fa fa-file-text"></i>Crear Ficha Técnica</a></li> ' +
    '            <li><a href="/Directorios/SubirDocumento?DirectorioId=' + data.id + '"><i class="fa fa-file"></i>Subir Documento</a></li > ' +
    '            <li><a href="#" onclick="BorraDir(' + data.id + ' )" data-id=' + data.id + '"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i>Eliminar Directorio</a></li> ' +
    '        </ul> ' +
    '    </div> ' +
    ' </td> ' +
    ' <td style="width:96%">' + Datos.Nombre + '</td> ' +
    '</tr>' +
    '<tr id="collapse-dir-' + data.id + '" class="collapse"> ' +
    '    <td colspan="4"> '+
    '        <table class="table table-condensed table-hover" id="table-dirs-' + data.id + '"> ' +
    '            <tbody> ' +
    '            </tbody> ' +
    '        </table> ' +
    '    </td>' +
    '</tr>').hide().fadeIn(1000);
```

Saludos.

Comment: append y appendTo no hacen lo mismo. ¿Estabas agregando el elemento?

Comment: Sí agregaba el elemento con .append() y debido a eso el .remove() no funcionaba, opté por utilizar appendTo(), y aquí funciona remove() correctamente, con append() había que refrescar la página para que funcionara.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner un ejemplo de cómo lo tenías antes y cómo lo tienes ahora? Para que pueda servir de guía a otros usuarios que se encuentren con el mismo problema en el futuro.